# Orion mosquitto JSON data

Tags: docker, mosquitto, fiware-orion

I have some issues with the Orion Context Broker. I am using raspberry pi to publish the JSON data to mosquitto broker that runs as a docker container. I can receive the data from the publisher, and the broker should pass the data to the Orion Context Broker. I created an entity like this:

```
curl localhost:1026/v2/entities -s -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
{
  "id": "SensTemp",
  "type": "Sensor",
  "temperature": {
     "value": 28,
     "type": "Float"
   }
 }
EOF
```

I can update the temperature value manually without any problems using the curl command. The problem is that the data from my mosquitto container doesnt go to the Orion Context Broker. Here are my docker containers:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

          mongo-db:
            image: mongo:3.6
            hostname: mongo-db
            container_name: db-mongo
            expose:
             - "27017"
            ports:
             - "27017:27017"
            networks:
             - default
            command: --bind_ip_all --smallfiles

          orion:
             image: fiware/orion
             ports:
                 - "1026:1026"
             networks:
                 - default
             depends_on:
                 - mongo-db
             command: -dbhost mongo-db -logLevel DEBUG
             healthcheck:
                   test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://0.0.0.0:1026/version"]
                   interval: 1m
                   timeout: 10s
                   retries: 3

          mqtt:
            image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
            container_name: mqtt
            ports:
              - "1883:1883"
              - "9001:9001"
            expose:
              - "1883"
              - "9001"
            volumes:
              - /opt/mosquitto/var/run:/var/run
```

Here is the proof of received data from my raspberry pi publisher:

[image: wiresharkproofmqttarriving]

How can I set up the Orion to get the data from my mosquitto container?

Comment: Yes every container works, I was able to send the data via mqtt publisher. The mosquitto container received the data (as you can see from wireshark photo) and that is it. The data should go to Orion Context Broker and the entity should change the value of the temperature... But Orion Doesnt use the data... Maybe i have made some mistake when i created entity? Or what should i do so the Orion gets the data from Mosquitto container? I should let you know that mosquitto orion and mongo are on my laptop, and the data published is from raspberry pi. If someone can help me please?

Comment: Where have you configured Orion to connect to the MQTT broker? What topics have you told it to subscribe to?

Comment: As for the topics, when i publish messages from my raspberry the name of the topic is "None". So maybe i should also put the name of the topic when i am creating the entity? I understand that topic is mentioned if i wanted to create a subscription...

Comment: How can i configure Orion?

Comment: Can i just tell the IOT agent to process the data from my mosquitto container? As i can understand, i only need to create a service in the IOT agent... And the rest will go automatically... But also should i create an entity? also a subscription? and a registration of the device? the data that is arriving from the raspberry is in {"temperature":10} JSON format, as you can see from the picture.

Comment: Also, when i want to create a service in my agent, i need to provide and "apikey"... if i dont provide it the service will not work, is there a way to bypass that order?

Comment: Update of the problem, I tried to add an entity to the agent like this: curl -X POST -H "Fiware-Service: myHome" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /environment" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
    "devices": [
        {
            "device_id": "SensTemp",
            "entity_name": "Sensor",
            "entity_type": "SensorT",
            "attributes": [
                  { "object_id": "temperature", "name": "temperature", "type": "celsius" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

' 'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices'

Comment: I was able to create an entity like that automatically on Orion and MongoDB, but still the messages dont arrive to them. I even modified my mosquitto container to listen to two ports 9001 and 1883 ( one for the Agent, the other for the remote raspberry)

Comment: I also implemented an "apikey" and the topic to be connected to the device id od the entity, but still my Orion context Broker nor agent doesnt recognize the message.

Comment: Does anyone has a pointer? Or a hint what should i do?

Comment: Update, I was able to get the JSON mqtt message to the agent! I only needed to create a service group and registration of the device on the agent. But now it gives me an error that i couldn't google out. msg=Parse error parsing incoming message[%], what should i do in order to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

When yo create the device, Did you indicate the transport?

For example

```
 "device_id":   "streetLight001",
 "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:StreetLight:001",
 "entity_type": "StreetLight",
 "protocol":    "PDI-IoTA-UltraLight",
 "transport":   "MQTT",
 "timezone":    "America/Bogota",
```

Comment: Uf... No, so maybe that is the problem? I only indicated "id", "type" and "temperature" as a value "float'... I will change the set up of the entity today! And i will let you know how it went! Thank you for the advice!!!!!!

Comment: Also, should i use that protocol? That is the agent protocol? Then i should implement an IOT agent as well?

Comment: I tried to create an entity like this: curl localhost:1026/v2/entities -s -S -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
> {
>  "id": "SensTemp",
>  "type": "Sensor",
>  "value": {
>   "temperature": 24.9,
>   "type": "Float"
>  },
>  "transport": "MQTT",
>  "timezone": "Europe/Valencia"
>  }
> EOF
{"error":"BadRequest","description":"unrecognized property for context attribute"}

Comment: And it gives me an error... What should i implement in entity creation besides "transport"?

Comment: I create my entity like this..... i define the attributes{
 "devices": [
   {
     "device_id":   "streetLight001",
  
     "timezone":    "America/Bogota",
     "attributes": [
       { "object_id": "luminaireSupplyVoltage", "name":"luminaireSupplyVoltage", "type":"Float"},
       { "object_id": "powerSupplyCurrent", "name":"powerSupplyCurrent", "type":"Float"},
       { "object_id": "powerState", "name":"powerState", "type":"Text"}
      ],
      "static_attributes": [
         {"name":"refStore", "type": "Relationship","value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Park:001"}
      ]
   }
 ]
}

Comment: Hi, it doesnt let me to add "transport" in the entity creation...

Answer (score 0):

When yo create the device, Did you indicate the transport and attributes (see this image)?
[entity creation with atributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoFoz.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for the example!!! I will try to implement that! But still, i think that i need to tell Orion and my Mosquitto container that receives the JSON data to pass it to Orion...

Comment: This looks like it should have been an edit to your original answer not a second answer.

Comment: I am trying to solve the problem, even my professor doesnt know how to help me... :)

Comment: This is my linkedin https://www.linkedin.com/in/faber-hernan-aristizabal-gomez-00860bb/ add me, we can talk

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved! The problem was in the Agent, i was using Ultralight IOT agent instead of the JSON Agent.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).